# How to download a File which is attached to my form in Openerp

Tags: file, download, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I have a file on my Server.I want to download the file in Openerp.If we take a "Back Up" of Database,the file will be downloaded and stored on local machine.
I want to do the same functionality but for a file which i have uploaded into a form in Openerp.AS of now I'm saving the file as a binary field in my database,
it will complex my searches operation.IN order to prevent it,I want to Download that file(like database back up file) on to my machine.
Can any one please say me how to do it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the Document Management System module provided by OpenERP then go to 'Knowledge' and click on the 'Documents' menu item.

You will see list of attached files(saved as binary in db), click on the required one, a form view will open which will have all the details regarding that attached file and there in the 'File Content' field you will find 'Download' link to download that file.

Once you click it ,that file gets downloaded on your machine.

Comment: I have done this. But this is stored in postgres DB (ir.attachement table)as binary format. I don't want to save in the db, it takes lot of memory. But what i want to do, I have some file outside of openerp in server, when i do some action, it should fetch data from hard disk.

Comment: Then I think you should check in the code of Google Docs module(openerp 7), where it uses the Document Management System of OpenERP to attach a file not in binary format but as URL.

Comment: i have tried that also. i was using widget=url attribute in character field for download file. This is working in local path (file:/Documents/file.pdf). but not working in server path.(local:8069/Documents/file.pdf)